# Why do firms bother to produce at equilibrium quantities if at equilibrium quantity, MR < MC?

Tags: microeconomics, supply-and-demand

For almost all demand curves, the resulting marginal revenue curve is often to the left of and steeper than the demand curve. The marginal cost curve has its distinctive U-shape, and a particular portion of the marginal cost curve is the supply curve. So the result can be shown below:
[image]

The figure above indicates that in almost any case, because MR is to the left of D, if a firm produces the quantity at market equilibrium, MR < MC, which means that the firm would be actively losing profits.  So, why do firms even bother going to market equilibrium - from a theoretical standpoint?

Answer (score 5):

The MC curve can only be seen as a supply schedule for the individual firm if it is a price taker. In the case you depicted, however, we have imperfect competition. A profit-maximizing firm will thus produce where MR=MC, and charge a price that will induce consumers to purchase this quantity (which can be read off the demand schedule). In this sense, there is no "disequilibrium": the firm is doing the best it can (so it has no reason to change), and total quantity demanded is equal to total quantity supplied (i.e. there is market equilibrium).

Comment: So for a market without perfect competition - this example could represent a monopoly or monopolistic competition, let's say - the market price and quantity supplied is determined not always naïvely by the intersection of the demand curve for the firm's product and the firm's supply curve?

Comment: And perhaps more generally, can the market equilibrium be determined by the intersection of the demand and supply curves only in the case of perfect competition?